# What is the Big O compexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I just need to check my understanding of how to analyze big - O complexity.
Is this algorithm N^2 or N^3? I'm aware of the many online resources explaining how to analyze an algorithm. I'd like to confirm my understanding.

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
 for(int j=0; j<n*n; j++)
 sum++
```

Comment: I am nearly 100% certain that I've seen precisely this question earlier today.  Looks like a new homework assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n^3) absolutely.

```
and T(n) = Ω(n^3).  
so T(n) = θ(n^3).`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!